# Calculating sum of array elements

Tags: c, arrays

```
I have written below the code for calculating sum of array element 
#include<stdio.h>
#define max 10
int main(){
   int arr[max]={214,542,455,145,1654,655,455,452,845,254};
   int sum=0,i;
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
     sum=sum+arr[i];
   printf("%d",sum);
   return 0;
}
```

The above code is giving the required result but for large array, execution  time will be    more.So i want to know that is there any other efficient way to calculate the sum for very large array such as for max=100001 and element is arr[i]<=10^9.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you need to "visit" each cell of the array in order to get the value and sum it. You're doing it good.

Comment: It is possible that splitting the array into multiple sections and summing them in parallel would be faster, but you are probably going to run into integer overflow with those numbers so you will want the sum to be a `long long`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use bigint to solve your problem.

Use libgmp http://gmplib.org/